# Using sequences to show that a function is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm stuck on this problem.

I have a set $S = [0,1)$ and a sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ converging to $x_0 = 1$, which is not in $S$. I need to show that I can found an unbounded, continuous function on $S$ and somehow need to use this sequence.

It's clear that $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ is unbounded on $S$. As $x$ gets arbitrarily close to $1$, it blows up. But how do I show that the function is unbounded? I can show that $f(x_n) \to +\infty$, but is that enough? $f$ is continuous on $S$, but because $x_0 \not \in S$, I can't say that $f$ maps limits to limits.

My main confusion is in showing how to use this sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Say $x_n \to 1$, and suppose that $f$ were bounded by $M$; that is, $|f(x)| = |1/(1-x)| \leq M$. Then it would follow that $|x_n| = |x_n(1-x_n)f(x_n)| \leq M|x_n(1-x_n)|$. Taking limits, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it s enough. The proof is by contradiction. Suppose $f$ is bounded. Then there exists a number $M \in (0,\infty)$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in S$. In particular this inequality must hold when $x=x_n$ so we get $|f(x_n)| \leq M$. But $f(x_n) \to \infty$ so there exists $n$ such that $f(x_n) >M$. We have reached a contradiction.

Comment: The problem I had with this idea, intuitively, is that I could take a constant sequence $(x_n)$ and repeat the same element again. But is the idea that $M$ is arbitrary, and given any $M$, I can find such an $x_n$, contradicting that there exists a bound at the level of the function?

Comment: A constant sequence wouldn't satisfy your hypothesis that $x_n \to 1$, but also it's not that you could find an $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) \geq M$, it's that there is some $x_M$ such that $f(x) \geq M$ whenever $x \geq x_M$. This is the definition of $f(x) \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to worry about the point $x=1$.

As long as you can prove $f(x_n)$ is unbounded on the interval $[0,1)$ you gain the unboundedness of your function on the same interval.

All you have to show is that for every positive real number $M$, there exists an $x\in [0,1)$ for which $f(x)>M$ and you can get your $x$ from the unbounded sequence $f(x_n)$